# How to use add layer for PointPlacemarks?

Tags: java, swing, worldwind

I am using World Wind for an application I am building for my employer. I've been following a [tutorial](http://ifgi.uni-muenster.de/worldwind-tutorial/?page_id=711) recommended by the official website, but while it's very simple to follow it is not very detailed. The method he is using in his tutorial for adding place markers won't work for me in my application because I don't want to be using an `ApplicationTemplate`.

I have created my `WorldWindowGLCanvas` object and have it centered in a `JPanel` using `BorderLayout`, like so;

```
wwd = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();
wwd.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());
wwd.setModel(new BasicModel());
wwd.getView().setEyePosition(Position.fromDegrees(53.044516, -1.659794, 65e4)); // Set initial view position. ie over England.
layer = new RenderableLayer();
...
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(wwd, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then (in a method from another class) I have created `PointPlacemark` objects and added them to `layer`...

```
pointPosition = Position.fromDegrees(periodical.getLatitude(), periodical.getLongitude());
placeMark = new PointPlacemark(pointPosition);
placeMark.setValue(AVKey.DISPLAY_NAME, periodical.getReference());
thisOne.layer.addRenderable(placeMark);
```

But now I can't figure out how to add that `layer` to my `WorldWindowGLCanvas` so that the `PointPlacemark`s will show up, or even if that *is* what I need to do. I have tried a whole host of (terrible) ideas, but so far nothing.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding layers is pretty simple.

```
wwd.getModel().getLayers().add(layer);
```

Edit:
Are you setting the image for the PointPlacemark by setting its Attributes?

```
PointPlacemarkAttributes atts = new PointPlacemarkAttributes();
atts.setImageAddress(String address);
placeMark.setAttributes(atts);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the Place Markers are still not visible on the map. Is there anything else that needs to be done? At least I know I wasn't too far off.

Comment: It's been a few months since I've actively coded with World Wind.  You may need to add a wwd.repaint() call after the layer is added.

Comment: As it turns out, you were correct the first time and my long and lat values are incorrect (it was painting, but painting them on the other side of the globe). I'll edit your answer back to how it was and accept it. >.<